# is this mapping well defined?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have to prove (or disprove)  that there exists a map $[a]\mapsto [at]$ from the set $ \mathbb{Z}_m^* $ to $ \mathbb{Z}_n^*$,
 if it is given that $m$ divides $n$, where $[a] \in \mathbb{Z}_m $ and $[at] \in \mathbb{Z}_n $ and t is such that $n=mt$.
My attempts to solve the problem: This is same as showing that the given mapping  is well defined, so I first show that that  for $$[a],[b] \in \mathbb{Z}_m^* ,[a]=[b] \implies [at]=[bt] \in \mathbb{Z}_n^*$$
which i easy as -if I assume $$ [a]=[b] \implies m\mid a-b$$
$$\implies a-b=mk ,k \in \mathbb{Z}$$
multiplying both sides by t,gives
                        $$at-bt=mtk$$
and $mt=n$
so this gives$$ at-bt=nk \implies n \mid at-bt \implies [at]=[bt]$$ both of which $\in \mathbb{Z}_n^*$.
Now, my question is-Is the proof I gave above is correct? Also, in my proof I never used the fact that  $gcd(a,m)=1$ and $gcd(at,n)=1$ so doesn't it mean that -it doesn't matter if I take $\mathbb{Z}_m$ or $\mathbb{Z}_m$, the mapping $[a] \mapsto [at]$ is always well defined?

**Edit:**: one more question(after reading HSN's answer): if $$(a,m)=1\implies ax+my=1$$ multiplying both sides by $t$ gives
 $$atx+mty=t\implies atx+ny=t$$ and for $(at,n)$to be equal to 1,  $t$ will have to be equal to be 1,now my intution says this mapping is not well defined in $\mathbb{Z}_m^*$ and $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$ case, but the above argument seems to be getting nowhere near this conclusion,what do i do now?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, the error is in stating "both of which $\in\mathbb{Z}_n^*$." To show well-definedness, there are two seperate parts to prove. First of all, as you're doing, that different representatives of a single class in $\mathbb{Z}_m$ are mapped to the same class in $\mathbb{Z}_n$, but if you want this to be a map $\mathbb{Z}_m^*\to\mathbb{Z}_n^*$, you will also have to show that the image of an invertible element is actually invertible in $\mathbb{Z}_n$. This, however isn't actually the case.

Take for instance the easiest possible case, $m=2$, $n=4$ (so $t=2$). The class of $1$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and its image under the given map would be $2\in\mathbb{Z}_4$, which most certainly isn't invertible.

Comment: thanks for the counterexample, it cleared up things a bit-that the two mappings are not at all same.

Comment: one more question: if $(a,m)=1\implies ax+my=1$multiplying both sides by t gives $atx+mty=t\implies atx+ny=t$ and for $(at,n)=1 t $ will have to be equal to be 1,now my intution says this mapping is not well defined in $\mathbb{Z}_m$ case, but the above argument seems to be getting nwhere near this conclusion,what do i do now?

Comment: I'm posting my above comment as an edit in my original question.